# When using Windows Deployment Services asks to reauthenticate

Tags: windows, pxe-boot, wds

We Use WDS to reimage computers over the network. When starting the install over the network it asks us to associate with the domain and user and password. However towards the end it makes us enter our domain username and password again. Is there anyway I can get it to install all the way through without asking to re authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Windows System Image Manager (apart of the Automated Install Kit) to create an unattend file, that specifies the domain and credentials with in it.